# css grid system where column width is dynamically determined?

Tags: css, grid

I have used 960gs to get a first version of some pages going (I am not the designer, but would like to have an approximate layout before handing it to one). It has helped me greatly, but now I am wondering if there is a CSS grid framework where the columns will expand/shrink to make use of all available space in the browser window. Using a 960 pixel top-level container in 960gs, even in my humble 1280-pixel-wide screen there are large empty bands on both sides.

Are there alternative grid systems where I can define a certain column to "grow" if the browser window is larger than expected?

Many thanks!

lara

Comment: While they exist, they more or less defeat the purpose of grid based design by giving the user the power to disrupt the visual rhythm the designer strove to achieve, not to mention introduce lines of type that may be of a completely inappropriate length for the font and/or leading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Fluid 960 Grid System](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/) too.

Answer (score 2):

See this ala article on [fluid grids](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids) and [example](http://www.alistapart.com/d/fluidgrids/examples/grid/entry.html). Also see [this example](http://fluid.newgoldleaf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Unsemantic](http://unsemantic.com/) it's from Nathan Smith who developed 960.gs.

Either that, or you can [customize Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html) so that you only take the responsive grid and leave out all the other features that might be unnecessary for your project.

Answer (score 0):

[**Cascade Framework**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/)'s grid system can do exactly what you want... and lots, lots more.

If you use the tag `<div class='site-center'></div>`, you get a centered div with a fixed width for desktop (width is different depending on browser width) and the full available width for mobile. You can, however, just drop that tag and use the full available width on desktop as well. See [**this website**](http://www.projekty-stajni.pl/) as an example of an implementation thereof.

The grid elements themselves are percentage based. That means that they fill up a certain percentage of the available width. Out of the box, Cascade Framework's grid system supports 60%/40%, 25%/75%, 33.33%/66.66%, 20%/20%/20%/20%/20%, 43.75%/31.25%/25%, 30%/30%/40% and far more combinations. In fact, you can even use combinations like 42.8571429%/{fill to 100%}, {fit content}/{fill to 100%} or {fit content}/30%/{fill to 100%}.

To be able to use Cascade Framework's grid system, I recommend you use either the file 'build-full.min.css' (about 8kb minified + gzipped) or the file 'build-full-no-icons.min.css' (about 10.8kb minified + gzipped) in the folder 'assets/css/cascade/production, depending on whether you want to include support for [**its icon set**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/icons.html). You can also create your own build and pick only the modules you want. For the sake of brevity, I'm skipping details on how to do that. If anything isn't clear about creating your own build and you'd like to know more about this, please send me a PM to avoid derailing this thread by going too far off-topic.

A grid element in Cascade framework is either

- One of the following HTML elements : section, main, article, header, footer, aside or nav (these elements are polyfilled with the HTMLshiv for old IE in case you need it).
- A div element with a 'col' class (can be used in old IE without a polyfill).

To add a width to a grid element, you add a class of the format 'width-XofY', where Y can be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16 or 24 and X can be any value lower than X.

More concretely, here are some examples of valid classes you can use in Cascade Framework : 'width-1of2' (width : 50%), 'width-3of4' (width : 25%), 'width-2of5' (width : 40%), 'width-2of5' (width : 40%), 'width-2of7' (width:28.5714286%) and 'width-13of16' (width:81.25%)

Additional to these classes, you can also use the classes 'width-fit' and 'width-fill' that respectively fit to content and fill whatever remains of your 100% width. Or, you could just define your own classes and IDs and just add a custom width for those classes to do things the 'semantic' way.

If your builds include the responsiveness module (which is the case for the recommended builds), the width of all grid elements automatic resets to 100% on mobile. You can use classes like 'mobile-width-3of16', 'phone-width-3of7' or 'tablet-width-2of4' to customize the layout for different width ranges and the classes 'desktop-hidden', 'mobile-hidden', 'phone-hidden' or 'tablet-hidden' to hide content for a specific screen with range.

See also http://www.cascade-framework.com/grid.html and http://jslegers.github.io/responsiveness/ .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Dead Simple Grid](http://mourner.github.io/dead-simple-grid/). You can set the columns to have fixed or percentage widths. Setting to percent will dynamically fill the available space. It is very simple (the entire css code is 250 bytes!) but surprisingly powerful.